# IE8 can't download some images, and the images it can't download change with each page refresh

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8, download, png

I am working on a leaflet map and had been thinking that IE8 was running the javascript very slowly, but now I think IE8 is just struggling with the images.  Oddly, though, the images IE8 can't handle seem to change with each page refresh.  Sometimes it hangs on a map icon, sometimes it hangs on the logo, etc.  If I do shift+F12 to use the profiler, and I click on Images -> View Image Report, the report takes a long time to load, and almost invariably some image won't load at all (red x).  But if I refresh, the image that failed to load previously might load without any problem at all, and a new image will fail.  In most cases, it is a transparent PNG that fails, but in some cases it's a PNG with no transparency.

By "fail", I mean the image doesn't download at all (red x) or it takes a minute or longer to download despite being less than 10 kb in size.

Comment: Does this happen with any other browser? If so then it might be a network issue.

Comment: No, just with IE8.  The following are fine:  IE9, FF, Chrome.